# How to transform (SELECT) rows of different types in new columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| Type | Value | Loc_x | Loc_y |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1   |   30  |   5   |   5   |
|  1   |   40  |   5   |   5   |
|  1   |   50  |   6   |   4   |
|  2   |   25  |   5   |   5   |
|  2   |   20  |   6   |   4   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

And need to make a SELECT that returns something like this:

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Type | Value | Type  | Value | Loc_x | Loc_y |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1   |   30  |   2   |   25  |   5   |   5   |
|  1   |   40  |   -   |   -   |   5   |   5   |
|  1   |   50  |   2   |   20  |   6   |   4   |
+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The algorithm should be:
- any type 1 row side by side with the any type 2 row when Loc_x and Loc_y are the same, while there are still rows to show.

ie every different type must be side by side when the Loc_x and Loc_y are the same.
When there isn't a corresponding value on any of the types, a - should be printed.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Mysql code for testing purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `loc_x` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `loc_y` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

insert  into `sample`(`id`,`type`,`value`,`loc_x`,`loc_y`) values (1,1,30,5,5);
insert  into `sample`(`id`,`type`,`value`,`loc_x`,`loc_y`) values (2,1,40,5,5);
insert  into `sample`(`id`,`type`,`value`,`loc_x`,`loc_y`) values (3,1,50,6,4);
insert  into `sample`(`id`,`type`,`value`,`loc_x`,`loc_y`) values (4,2,25,5,5);
insert  into `sample`(`id`,`type`,`value`,`loc_x`,`loc_y`) values (5,2,20,6,4);
```

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "first type 2 row" unless you have a column that represents the ordering.

Comment: Do you need to have the multiple 'Type' fields in the output?  It might make more sense to have your output be Type_1_Value, Type_2_Value, Loc_x, Loc_y.

Comment: Are those types a well defined set? I mean, does column Type hold only 1 and 2, or can it hold any number of values?

Comment: Gordon Linoff: no need for "first type 2 row". I've just edited the question.
Curly_Jefferson: could be precisely as you suggest.. Type_1_Value, Type_2_Value, Loc_x, Loc_y.
Mariano D'Ascanio: yes, unsigned tinyints (<255)

Comment: If Type can have up to 255 values, I think the best approach would be to build the output table and run a program for each Type to first update records where a location match is found and then append records where no match was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on MySQL:

```
select 
    type1.type,
    type1.value,
    type2.type,
    type2.value,
    type1.Loc_x,
    type1.Loc_y
from 
    (select * , 
            COALESCE((select 0
                      from sample as sample_t
                      where 
                         sample_t.id < sample_a.id 
                           and
                         sample_a.loc_x = sample_t.loc_x
                           and 
                         sample_a.loc_y = sample_t.loc_y
                           and 
                         type = 1
                      limit 1), 1) as is_first 
     from sample as sample_a
     where type = 1) as type1
    left join
    (select *
     from sample
     where type = 2) as type2
    on 
        type1.Loc_x = type2.Loc_x
        and type1.Loc_y = type2.Loc_y
        and type1.is_first = 1
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your output can have multiple columns of the same name.  So this method won't produce your output exactly.

```
SELECT sub_type_1.Value as Value_1,
  sub_type_2.Value as Value_2,
  coalesce(sub_type_1.loc_x, sub_type_2.loc_x) as Loc_x
  coalesce(sub_type_1.loc_y, sub_type_2.loc_y) as Loc_y
FROM 
  (SELECT TYPE, Value, Loc_x, Loc_y FROM [Input] WHERE TYPE = 1) sub_type_1
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT TYPE, Value, Loc_x, Loc_y FROM [Input] WHERE TYPE = 2) sub_type_2
  ON sub_type_1.Loc_x = sub_type_2.Loc_x
  AND sub_type_1.Loc_y = sub_type_2.Loc_y
```

Comment: To Mariano's comment above, this method would only make sense if you had a small number of possible values in 'Type'

Comment: Just noticed that MySQL doesn't have the FULL OUTER JOIN clause. Is there any alternative?